# Reordering pandas dataframe based on multiple column and sum of one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
              Country_FAO            type   mean_area
0             Afghanistan             car   2029000.0
1             Afghanistan             car    112000.0
2                 Algeria             bus    827000.0
3                 Algeria             bus      2351.0
4               Australia             car   6475695.0
5               Australia             car  12141000.0
6               Australia             bus    293806.0
```

I would like to reorder this dataframe on the basis of sum of `mean_area`for each value in the `Country_FAO` column. The end result should look like this:

```
              Country_FAO            type   mean_area
0               Australia             car  12141000.0
1               Australia             car   6475695.0
2               Australia             bus    293806.0
3             Afghanistan             car   2029000.0
4             Afghanistan             car    112000.0
5                 Algeria             bus    827000.0
6                 Algeria             bus      2351.0
```

Australia comes first because the sum of `mean_area` values for its 3 categories is the highest.

I tried this:

```
df_stacked.sort(['Country_FAO', 'mean_area'], ascending=[False, False])
```

This does not work though, it does not add up all the `mean_area`s before doing the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create new column `sort` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). Last you can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) it with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df['sort'] = df.groupby('Country_FAO')['mean_area'].transform(sum)

df['sort'] = df.groupby('Country_FAO')['mean_area'].transform(sum)

df1 = df.sort_values(['sort','Country_FAO', 'mean_area'], ascending=False)
print df1
   Country_FAO type   mean_area        sort
5    Australia  car  12141000.0  18910501.0
4    Australia  car   6475695.0  18910501.0
6    Australia  bus    293806.0  18910501.0
0  Afghanistan  car   2029000.0   2141000.0
1  Afghanistan  car    112000.0   2141000.0
2      Algeria  bus    827000.0    829351.0
3      Algeria  bus      2351.0    829351.0

df1 = df1.drop('sort', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print df1
   Country_FAO type   mean_area
0    Australia  car  12141000.0
1    Australia  car   6475695.0
2    Australia  bus    293806.0
3  Afghanistan  car   2029000.0
4  Afghanistan  car    112000.0
5      Algeria  bus    827000.0
6      Algeria  bus      2351.0
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, is there a way to make the 'sort' column a part of a pipe?

Comment: Very hard question, I never seen it.

Comment: thanks! plz have a look at a related query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755287/accepting-top-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-grouping