# Accepting top rows in pandas dataframe based on grouping

Tags: python, pandas

Related to the question here: [Reordering pandas dataframe based on multiple column and sum of one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754958/reordering-pandas-dataframe-based-on-multiple-column-and-sum-of-one-column/36755006?noredirect=1#comment61090631_36755006)

How can I accept the top 2 countries in this dataframe, when using `sort` column:
In this case, the top 2 countries will be Australia and Afghanistan

```
  Country_FAO type   mean_area        sort
5    Australia  car  12141000.0  18910501.0
4    Australia  car   6475695.0  18910501.0
6    Australia  bus    293806.0  18910501.0
0  Afghanistan  car   2029000.0   2141000.0
1  Afghanistan  car    112000.0   2141000.0
2      Algeria  bus    827000.0    829351.0
3      Algeria  bus      2351.0    829351.0
```

--EDIT:

I also want to retain the `type` column. In this case, the solution should look like:

```
Country_FAO type   mean_area        sort
5    Australia  car  12141000.0  18910501.0
4    Australia  car   6475695.0  18910501.0
6    Australia  bus    293806.0  18910501.0
0  Afghanistan  car   2029000.0   2141000.0
1  Afghanistan  car    112000.0   2141000.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [166]: df.loc[df.Country_FAO.isin(df.groupby('Country_FAO').sum().nlargest(2, 'mean_area').index)]
Out[166]:
   Country_FAO type   mean_area        sort
5    Australia  car  12141000.0  18910501.0
4    Australia  car   6475695.0  18910501.0
6    Australia  bus    293806.0  18910501.0
0  Afghanistan  car   2029000.0   2141000.0
1  Afghanistan  car    112000.0   2141000.0
```

i would do it this way:

```
In [153]: df.groupby('Country_FAO').sum()
Out[153]:
              mean_area
Country_FAO
Afghanistan   2141000.0
Algeria        829351.0
Australia    18910501.0

In [154]: df.groupby('Country_FAO').sum().nlargest(2, 'mean_area')
Out[154]:
              mean_area
Country_FAO
Australia    18910501.0
Afghanistan   2141000.0

In [155]: df.groupby('Country_FAO').sum().nlargest(2, 'mean_area').index
Out[155]: Index(['Australia', 'Afghanistan'], dtype='object', name='Country_FAO')
```

also, you may want to reset your index:

```
In [156]: df.groupby('Country_FAO').sum().nlargest(2, 'mean_area').reset_index()
Out[156]:
   Country_FAO   mean_area
0    Australia  18910501.0
1  Afghanistan   2141000.0
```

Comment: thanks @MaxU, this soln does remove the `type` column, is there a way to retain that?